# The calculation result always a 'NaN'

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

```js
let z = document.getElementById('id_z')
let x = document.getElementById('id_x')
let y = document.getElementById('id_y')


$("#id_a, #id_b, #id_c, #id_d, #id_e").keyup(function () {
    let a = $('#id_a').val()
    let b = $('#id_b').val()
    let c = $('#id_c').val()
    let d = $('#id_d').val()
    let e = $('#id_e').val()
    
    z.value = ((c * 3.175) / a).toFixed(0)
    x.value = (b*e)+(d*(e - 1))+15
    
    // y variable throws the error
    y.value = ((c*3.175) - (a * z))/z
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Value A:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_a">

<label>Value B:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_b">

<label>Value C:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_c">

<label>Value D:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_d">

<label>Value E:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_e">

<div>
<label>Value Z:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_z">

<label>Value x:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_x">

<label>Value Y:</label>
<input type="number" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_y">
</div>
```

I am creating a calculation process using JavaScript based on what the user input and delivering the result. When I try to put a number in "gear", it shows the error in the console "specified value cannot be parsed or is out of range".

```
const z = document.getElementById('id_z')
const x = document.getElementById('id_x')
const y = document.getElementById('id_y')


$("#id_c, #id_d, #id_e, #id_a, #id_b").keyup(function () {
    const a = $('#id_a').val()
    const b = $('#id_b').val()
    const c = $('#id_c').val()
    const d = $('#id_d').val()
    const e = $('#id_e').val()
    
    z.value = ((c * 3.175) / a).toFixed(0)
    x.value = (a*e)+(d*(e - 1)+15)
    
    // y variable throws the error
    y = ((c*3.175) - (a * z))/z
    
    console.log(y)
    console.log(typeof(y))
});
```

For z and x looks fine but the calculation result for X always throws NaN. I need some advice on this problem, Thank you.

Comment: `.val()` gives you _string_ values, not numbers. You can't perform arithmetic with them yet, turn them into numbers first (using parseFloat, not parseInt). The fact that `z` and `x` seem to work is essentially an accident.

Comment: Your code should be erroring, you created a `const y` and then tried to reassign it, and to a different type????  Try to create [runnable snippets] instead of just posting the code. It will surely improve the quality of your question and make it more likely that others will want to help.

Comment: As also @RuanMendes requested, please provide a [mre] as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). This question could have been conclusively answered 20 minutes ago.

Comment: And many of us won't help because it takes extra time. It also doesn't look like [you have tried to debug it](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Or at least you didn't tell us about it.

Comment: `((c*3.175) - (a * z))/z` -> `((c*3.175) - (a * z.value))/z.value` or otherwise don't use *the element* which is `z` in a mathematical calculation but *its value*. Assuming it's an input.

Comment: Hello, I already add the runnable snippet to make my question clear..

Comment: As noted above, what's the value of `z` in `..(a * z))/z`?   z = document.getElementById - z is a DOM node, you're dividing by a DOM node?  That's *N*ot *a* *N*umber...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) `.val()` provides value in string format so you have to convert it into numbers. So use `parseFloat`.

b) Instead of using constant use `var` or `let` as the constant value cannot be changed each time the different input values change.

c) As `x,y,z` are DOM elements so you can not use them directly in your calculation. You need to change your code like below.

Working snippet:

```js
var z = document.getElementById('id_z')
var x = document.getElementById('id_x')
var y = document.getElementById('id_y')

$("#id_c, #id_d, #id_e, #id_a, #id_b").keyup(function() {
  var a = parseFloat($('#id_a').val()) || 0;
  var b = parseFloat($('#id_b').val()) || 0;
  var c = parseFloat($('#id_c').val()) || 0;
  var d = parseFloat($('#id_d').val()) || 0;
  var e = parseFloat($('#id_e').val()) || 0;

  var first = ((c * 3.175) / a).toFixed(0);
  var second = (a * e) + (d * (e - 1) + 15);
  var third = ((c * 3.175) - (a * first)) / first;

  z.value = first;
  x.value = second;
  y.value = !isNaN(third) ? third : 0;
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]
{
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
id_a<input type="text" id="id_a">
<br> id_b
<input type="text" id="id_b">
<br> id_c
<input type="text" id="id_c">
<br> id_d
<input type="text" id="id_d">
<br> id_e
<input type="text" id="id_e">
<br> id_x

<input type="text" id="id_x">
<br> id_y

<input type="text" id="id_y">
<br> id_z
<input type="text" id="id_z">
<br>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do parseFloat() in javascript to prevent this.
Below is the code for your problem:

```
let a = parseFloat($('#id_a').val());
let b = parseFloat($('#id_b').val());
let c = parseFloat($('#id_c').val());
let d = parseFloat($('#id_d').val());
let e = parseFloat($('#id_e').val());
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: OPs actual issue is `123 / document.getElementById('id_z')`